# How do I embed an AppleScript in a Python script?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I am trying to embed an AppleScript in a Python script. I don't want to have to save the AppleScript as a file and then load it in my Python script. Is there a way to enter the AppleScript as a string in Python and have Python execute the AppleScript? Thanks a bunch.

Here is my script:
    import subprocess
    import re
    import os

```
def get_window_title():
    cmd = """osascript<<END
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    end tell
    tell application frontApp
        if the (count of windows) is not 0 then
            set window_name to name of front window
        end if
    end tell
    return window_name
    END"""

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    p.terminate()
    return p

def get_class_name(input_str):
    re_expression = re.compile(r"(\w+)\.java")
    full_match = re_expression.search(input_str)
    class_name = full_match.group(1)
    return class_name

print get_window_title()
```

Comment: Just for your information, there's a little python module on PyPI that do the trick : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-applescript/0.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

scpt = '''
    on run {x, y}
        return x + y
    end run'''
args = ['2', '2']

p = Popen(['osascript', '-'] + args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
print(p.returncode, stdout, stderr)
```

Comment: In python 3 this would not work, an additional parameter universal_newlines=True on the popen is needed. See example below https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133926/1534775

Comment: @gbonetti this is not necessarily true.  In python 3 this can actually introduce more errors if your script text contains non-ascii characters.  You might need to leave the `universal_newlines` off and encode the script as necessary. Ex. `stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt.encode('utf-8'))` and then `stdout.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 9):

In python 3 it would be slightly different:

```
script = 'tell "some application" to do something'
p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(script)
```

Popen now expects a byte-like object, to pass a string, the `universal_newlines=True` parameter is needed.

Comment: In python 3 this will fail if the script contains non-ascii characters.  A better way would be to do `universal_newlines=False` and then encode the `script` and decode `stdout` as necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer removes the "+ args" for no apparent reason.  (a mistake?)  Anyway, what worked for me was using code from user "Has"'s accepted answer, and just adding universal_newlines=True as last parameter in function call.

Answer (score 6):

Example 3 in [this article](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/05/08/using-python-and-applescript-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-mac.html) suggests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#sleepy-mac.py
#makes my mac very sleepy

import os
cmd = """osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to sleep'"""
def stupidtrick():
     os.system(cmd)
stupidtrick()
```

These days, however, `subsystem.Popen` is usually preferred over `os.system` (the article is from three years ago, when nobody screamed on seeing an `os.system` call;-).

Comment: I looked at that link before, and I couldn't quite get my script working. I edited my question to include the script I am trying to perform. I think the error is that I can't retrieve the return value from the AppleScript. I looked into the Popen object, but I couldn't find anything to operate on return values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple python3 synchronous example, if you want your python code not to wait for Applescript to finish.  In this example, both `say` commands are executed in parallel.

```
from subprocess import Popen

def exec_applescript(script):
    p = Popen(['osascript', '-e', script])

exec_applescript('say "I am singing la la la la" using "Alex" speaking rate 140 pitch 60')
exec_applescript('say "Still singing, hahaha" using "Alex" speaking rate 140 pitch 66')
```

Answer (score 4):

`subprocess.run()` is [now preferred](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) over `subprocess.popen()`. Here is a pretty simple way to run AppleScript code and get the results back.

```
import subprocess

def get_window_title():
    cmd = """
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
        end tell
        tell application frontApp
            if the (count of windows) is not 0 then
                set window_name to name of front window
            end if
        end tell
        return window_name
    """
    result = subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', cmd], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout

print(get_window_title())
```

Comment: Python 3.6 required the `, capture_output=True` portion to be removed from subrpocess.run for this to work

Answer (score 3):

See https://pypi.org/project/applescript/

```
import applescript
resp = applescript.tell.app("System Events",'''
set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
return "Done"
''')
assert resp.code == 0, resp.err
print(resp.out)
```

etc.
Most of suggestions, including "applescript" I quoted, are missing one important setting to osascript -- setting an -s option to "s", otherwise you will be having difficulty parsing the output.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than embedding AppleScript, I would instead use [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/).  I've never used the Python version, but it was very nice in Ruby.  [And make sure that, if you're installing it on Snow Leopard, you have the latest version of XCode.](http://soenkerohde.com/2010/03/running-project-sprouts/)  <s>However, I've so far been unable to install it on Snow Leopard.  But I've only had Snow Leopard for ~1 day, so your mileage may vary.</s>

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having problems; it should work (it does here). Have you tried posting on rb-appscript-discuss (http://rubyforge.org/mail/?group_id=2346) for help?

Comment: has: Thanks for the link, but I only installed Snow Leopard 1.5 days ago, and I spent today traveling; I haven't really tried very hard yet.  Still, I'll check it out if I can't make it work; thanks again.

Comment: has: And indeed, all I needed to do was [update XCode](http://soenkerohde.com/2010/03/running-project-sprouts/).  Thanks again, though!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. And yes, if the OP doesn't mind a third-party install, then py-appscript is a much nicer solution. e.g. This'll get the names of all windows in the frontmost process: `app('System Events').application_processes[its.frontmost==True].first.windows.name()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic function in python. Just pass your applescript code with/without args and get back the value as a string. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941735/679390) answer.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def run_this_scpt(scpt, args=[]):
    p = Popen(['osascript', '-'] + args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
    return stdout

#Example of how to run it.
run_this_scpt("""tell application "System Events" to keystroke "m" using {command down}""")

#Example of how to run with args.
run_this_scpt('''
    on run {x, y}
        return x + y
    end run''', ['2', '2'])
```

Comment: Python 3.6 runs without error if `universal_newlines=True` is added at the end of Popen parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system('''
    osascript -e 
     '[{YOUR SCRIPT}]'
     '[{GOES HERE}]'
    ''')
```

or, as suggested by Alex Martelli you can use a variable:

```
import os
script = '''
    [{YOUR SCRIPT}]
    [{GOES HERE}]
'''
os.system('osascript -e ' + script)
```