# How to run an AppleScript from within a Python script?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

How to run an AppleScript from within a Python script?

The questions says it all..
(On a Mac obviously)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[this nice article](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2007/05/08/using-python-and-applescript-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-mac.html) suggests the simple solution

```
cmd = """osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to sleep'"""
def stupidtrick():
    os.system(cmd)
```

though today you'd use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, of course.

Be sure to also check [page 2](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/05/08/using-python-and-applescript-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-mac.html?page=2) of the article for many more info and options, including [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: If you going to do any kind of non-trivial Apple Event scripting from Python, you should be using appscript. It's well-designed, mature, and well-supported.

Comment: @Ned, sure, but for such a simple, specific purpose as calling a simple bit of applescript, the "stupid trick" of `osascript -e` and `subprocess.call`, as suggested in the article's page 1 (well the article as I mentions uses the old `os.system`, but that's a detail;-) might suffice.

Comment: Oh, Alex, I certainly wasn't disagreeing with *you*!

Comment: @Ned, nor was I disagreeing with you (that's why I say "sure";-), so we appear to be in furious agreement;-).

Comment: appscript isn't supported anymore unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean "it's not supported anymore"?

Comment: @speedyrazor - From the appscript page on SourceForge "Please note that appscript is no longer developed or supported, and its use is not recommended for new projects." http://appscript.sourceforge.net

Comment: The 'nice article' link to O'Reilly is now broken.

Answer (score 6):

A `subprocess` version which allows running an original apple script as-is, without having to escape quotes and other characters which can be tricky. It is a simplified version of the script found [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/03/combining-python-and-applescript/) which also does parametrization and proper escaping (Python 2.x).

```python
import subprocess

script = '''tell application "System Events"
    activate
    display dialog "Hello Cocoa!" with title "Sample Cocoa Dialog" default button 2
end tell
'''

proc = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_output = proc.communicate(script)[0]
print stdout_output
```

> <sup>NOTE: If you need to execute more than one script with the same Popen instance then you'll need to write explicitly with `proc.stdin.write(script)` and read with `proc.stdout.read()` because `communicate()` will close the input and output streams.</sup>

Comment: In python 3 this would not work, an additional parameter universal_newlines=True on the popen is needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133926/1534775

Answer (score 0):

I got the Output folks... Here it's following:

```
import subprocess
import sys

for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
    ip = str(sys.argv[2])
    username = str(sys.argv[3])
    pwd = str(sys.argv[4])

    script = '''tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "cd Desktop && python test_switch.py {ip} {username} {pwd}"
        delay 15
    end tell
    '''

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_output = proc.communicate(script.format(ip=ip, username=username, pwd=pwd))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty frustrated at the lack of detail in Apple's own documentation regarding how to do this AND to also pass in arguments. I had to send the desired arg (in this case a zoom id) as a string otherwise the argument didn't come through to the applescript app

Here's my code running from python:

```
f = script if os.path.exists(script) else _tempfile()

if not os.path.exists(script):
            open(f,'w').write(script)
args = ["osascript", f, str(zoom_id)]

kwargs = {'stdout':open(os.devnull, 'wb'),'stderr':open(os.devnull, 'wb')}
        #kwargs.update(params)
proc = subprocess.Popen(args,**kwargs)
```

and here is my applescript:

```
on run argv
    set zoom_id to 0
    zoom_id = item 1 in argv
    tell application "zoom.us"
       --do stuff
    end tell
end run
```