# Change mac terminal size from within python code

Tags: python

I think the reason I can't find answers to this is because it's not a thing. But I want to change the size of my mac terminal from within my python code. I'm working on a little game project and want to add ASCII art but also want it to be formatted correctly across OS's. I've dug into the os python library and hit all the walls with that. But if you have any answer at all (even if its that it can't be done), that would save me so much time.

Comment: So are you outputting into a terminal and you want to change the size of that terminal?

Comment: I think you may have to do this in AppleScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940916/how-do-i-embed-an-applescript-in-a-python-script

Comment: This (unrelated) bug talks about the VT escape sequences to do it: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094 (that aren't correctly supported in Windows Terminal).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.